# array formula for --(B2*SUM(C2:E2)>0) for 10 rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to see if B2*SUM(C2:E2) is greater than zero. If yes, the result should be one, otherwise, zero. Then, I'd like to do this for 10 rows, say, row 2 to 11, and sum the results. The final result should be between 0 and 10.

Possible to create an array formula to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only 3 columns in the sum the simplest way is like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B11*(C2:C11+D2:D11+E2:E11)>0)+0)`

....or do you need it to be more generic? In which case try this version where you can easily expand the range to any number of columns

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B11*SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2:E11,ROW(C2:E11)-MIN(ROW(C2:E11)),0,1))>0)+0)`

In this latter version `OFFSET` function is used to generate the separate ranges for each row and then `SUBTOTAL` totals each range